# Why is Excel datatime distorted in Python

Tags: python, excel, csv, date

I read excel csv data in Python, at first it was okay, I've been working on the dataframe in VS Code. Today I realised that the date data was distorted, ie., instead of `'2021-01-06'` it shows `'2021-06-01'` which is wrong. After comparing to the backup data, it shows that some dates remain correct, such as `'2021-01-03'` while the rest have been changed such as `'2021-06-01'` when read in Python. But when I checked the data in Excel it seemed correct, ie., `'2021-01-06'`.

I did not open the csv file directly but only read from VS Code. Has Excel changed the date? I find this confusing and misleading as you don't know when the data is changed. What's the reason and how can we prevent this?

Comment: it might be ambiguous between computer datetime and others, it could cause from Excel or event Python during processing. In this case, I always config in excel column by UTC date time, or Unix, or simply '2021-Jan-06'

Comment: Hi @TấnNguyên do you mind providing more details on config in excel column?

Comment: Open your csv data by Excel, the column make it custom format such as yyyy-MMM-dd => '2021-Jan-06' basically. Recheck and save it back to csv file, it will never be ambiguous when the data is processed by any PC with US, UK, Asian,.. date format.